# The Duals of $l^\infty$ and $L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

Can we identify the dual space of $l^\infty$ with another "natural space"?  If the answer is yes, what can we say about $L^\infty$?
By the dual space I mean the space of all continuous linear functionals.

Comment: This paper could be helpful, I hope https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByszALzBG-7kUlRDUlpwUERyeUE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes, if $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a (complete) $\sigma$-finite measure space then $(L^{\infty}(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu))^{\ast}$ is the space $\operatorname{ba}(\Omega, \Sigma,\mu)$  of all finitely additive finite signed measures defined on $\Sigma$, which are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, equipped with the total variation norm. The proof is relatively easy and can be found e.g. in Dunford-Schwartz, *Linear Operators I*, Theorem IV.8.16, page 296.

I should add that in that theorem Dunford-Schwartz treat the general case as well, which is a bit messier to state. The duality is the one you would expect, namely "integration". As far as I know, the bidual space of $L^{\infty}$ does not have an explicit analytic description, however (whatever that should mean precisely).

Moreover, the canonical embedding $L^{1}(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu) \to \operatorname{ba}{(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)}$ is of course the map sending $f$ to the signed measure $d\nu = f\,d\mu$. In the $\sigma$-finite case, the image of this map can be recovered by looking at the $\sigma$-additive measures via the Radon-Nikodym theorem (and $\sigma$-additivity corresponds of course precisely to weak$^{\ast}$-continuity of the functionals on $L^{\infty} = (L^1)^{\ast}$).

Comment: Quite a while later but what is "Ba" here?

Comment: 'Ba' stands for bounded additive -- look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space) for more info.

Comment: Can this description of the dual of $L^\infty$ be leveraged to prove the existence of conditional expectation of an integrable random variable without invoking Radon-Nikodym? I asked a question about a "functional analytic" proof of existence of conditional expectations yesterday and this thread was linked in an answer. I guess yes, since you say that weak${}^*$ continuity $\iff$ $\sigma$-additivity and $\sigma$-additivity is clear for $Z\mapsto\mathbf{E}[ZX]$. Can you recommend a source for this material?

Answer (score 41):

This is perhaps not such a nice characterization as finitely additive measures on $\mathbb N$, but it might be worth mentioning. (You can look it as follows: We obtain  nicer measures - $\sigma$-additive instead of finitely additive - on a more complicated space - $\beta\mathbb N$ instead of $\mathbb N$.)

The space $\ell_\infty$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(\beta\mathbb N)$, hence the dual is isomorphic to $C^*(\beta\mathbb N)$.

More details about the correspondence between $\ell_\infty$ and the Stone-Cech compactification of integers can be found at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-Cech_compactification#An_application%3a_the_dual_space_of_the_space_of_bounded_sequences_of_reals) or in [chapter 15](http://books.google.com/books?id=pec4r3EsIiMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Carothers%20banach&hl=en&ei=1IkETozGL8jNswa9xoWTDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=stone%20cech&f=false) of Carothers' book A short course on Banach space theory.

Now, $C^*(\beta\mathbb N)$ is the space of regular Borel measures on $\beta\mathbb N$ by [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

In fact, Carothers goes the other way round. First, the dual of $C^*(\beta\mathbb N)$ is described via finitely additive measures. And then he uses this to prove Riesz representation theorem for compact spaces. (This proof of Riesz' representation theorem  is due to Garling.)

Comment: Of course, I should have mentioned that. In fact, every $L^{\infty}$-space is a space of the form $C(K)$ where $K$ is compact and extremally disconnected (= hyperstonian), thus every dual of $L^\infty$ can be implemented as space of measures on *some* compact space. I prefer the proof via $C^{\ast}$-theory: look at the space $K$ of states on the commutative unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra $L^{\infty}$ (this is of course somewhat circular, as $K$ is a subset of $(L^{\infty})^{\ast}$).

Comment: @Theo: I might misunderstand what you're saying, but if $L^\infty\cong C(K)$, then $K$ is the maximal ideal space (or character space), not the state space.

Comment: @Jonas: No, that was a plain mistake on my part (I simply confused characters and states -- I'm no operator theorist). Sorry about that and thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm upvoting your comment anyway because it makes some good points.