# What is the dual of $L^{\infty}(K)$ with K a compact subset of $R^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know it's probably hard to describe the dual of  $L^{\infty}(X)$ for a general $X$. But can we describe it when $X$ is just a compact subset of a Euclidean space?

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/the-duals-of-l-infty-and-l-infty) may be helpful.