# Sequences in $(\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}))'$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the real Banach space $X = \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$. Show that there exists a functional $\Lambda \in X^\prime$ such with the following properties:
$$\inf \{x_n\} \le \Lambda(x) \le \sup \{x_n\} \forall x\in X$$
$$\Lambda(x) = \lim x_n, \forall x\in X \text{ such that} \lim x_n \text{ exists}$$
$$\Lambda(Sx) = \Lambda(x), x\in X, \text{where $S$ is the left shift: $(Sx)_n = x_{n+1}$}$$

I am fairly certain I am missing something obvious but I currently don't have a guess for this. To me, it seems this must be a constant sequence based on the third condition
$$\Lambda(Sx) = \Lambda(x), x\in X, \text{where $S$ is the left shift: $(Sx)_n = x_{n+1}$}$$
Is this not the case? If not, why not and what fits the bill?

Comment: For converging sequences the functional that maps a sequence to its limit does the job. A suitable application of Hahn Banach should be the next step.

Comment: @P.Pet It isn't that straightforward to show that there is a Hahn-Banach extension of the limit functional on $c$ that is still invariant under (the adjoint of) the left shift.

Comment: I originally read the question as if the left shift property was only required for sequences where the limit exists. But it seems like this is not what is meant here.

Answer (score 2):

The topological dual of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is too large to assume that such a functional $\Lambda$ must have a representation as some sequence (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47400/256128) for a characterisation of the dual).  In particular, it is not the case that $\Lambda(Sx) = \Lambda(x)$ implies that $\Lambda$ is the action of a constant sequence.

In what follows, where I use $1$ in the place a sequence should be I mean $(1,1, 1,\dots) \in \ell^\infty$. One approach is the following:

Consider the operator $T = I-S$. Then $\Lambda(Sx) = \Lambda(x)$ for every $x$ iff $T(\ell^\infty) \subset \ker \Lambda$. One can show that the kernel of $T$ consists of the constant sequences and that if $Y = \ker T \oplus T(\ell^\infty)$ then the projection $P$ onto $\ker T$ along $T(\ell^\infty)$ is bounded (with norm $1$).

Now define $\pi_1(x) = x_1$ for $x \in \ell^\infty$ and define $\Lambda_0: Y \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\Lambda_0 = \pi_1 \circ P$. It is easily shown that $\Lambda_0$ is a norm $1$ functional such that $\Lambda_0(1) = 1$.

By Hahn-Banach, there is a norm $1$ functional, $\Lambda$, on $\ell^\infty$ extending $\Lambda_0$. By construction, $T(\ell^\infty) \subset \ker P \subset \ker \Lambda_0 \subset \ker \Lambda$ so $\Lambda(Sx) = \Lambda(x)$. It is less clear that $\Lambda$ has the other two properties. This will follow from the following result which was in fact the rest of my motivation for defining $\Lambda_0$ in the way I did.

> **Lemma:** Suppose $f \in (\ell^\infty)^*$ with $\|f\| = 1$. Then $f(Sx) = f(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(1) = 1$ implies $\lim \inf \{x_n\} \leq f(x) \leq \lim \sup \{x_n \}$ for every $x \in \ell^\infty$.

You can prove this by showing that such an $f$ is then non-negative in the sense that $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ implies $f(x) \geq 0$ and then e.g. considering $f(S^nx - \alpha 1)$ for $\alpha < \lim \inf \{x_n\}$ where $n$ is chosen so that $x_{n+m} > \alpha$ for every $m$.

The other two desired properties of $\Lambda$ then follow in a straightforward manner.

---

In fact, there is another more general technique for proving this result that needs some heavier machinery. As noted in the comments, on the space of convergent sequences $c \subset \ell^\infty$, the limit functional matches the requirements. So one might attempt to take a Hahn-Banach extension $\Phi$ of $\lim : c \to \mathbb{R}$ and hope that this still has the desired properties.

By my Lemma and its definition, $\Phi$ will satisfy the first two properties. However, it is not obvious that $\Phi(Sx) = \Phi(x)$ for every $x$ (this is the reason that I constructed $\Lambda_0$ on a space other than $c$ above; I was most worried about this property).

It is in fact true that you can find a Hahn-Banach extension with the desired property. The key is to recognise that $\Phi(Sx) = \Phi(x)$ for every $x$ iff $\Phi$ is a fixed point of $S^*$. In fact, we actually don't even need to be working with the shift operator $S$ on $\ell^\infty$. More generally, we have

> **Theorem:** Let $Y$ be a subspace of a Banach space $X$ and let $T:X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator. If $g \in Y^*$ and $g(Tx) = g(x)$ for every $x \in Y$ then there is $f \in X^*$ such that $f$ extends $g$, $\|f\| = \|g\|$ and $f(Tx) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

The idea of the proof is to apply the [Markov-Kakutani Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) to $T^*$ defined on the set $\{ f \in X^*: \|f\| = \|g\| \text{ and } f \text{ extends } g \}$. This set is non-empty by Hahn-Banach, is easily seen to be convex and, by an application of Banach-Alaoglu, is weak$^*$-compact since it is clearly weak$^*$ closed. So by Markov-Kakutani, we get the desired functional.

In fact, one can generalise this even further to find Hahn-Banach extensions that preserve the property $f(T_ix) = f(x)$ for every $x$ as long as the $T_i$ commute (again just Markov-Kakutani) but this answer is already quite long so I won't go into details here.

Answer (score 0):

The left shift takes a sequence and gives you a new sequence without the first element of the sequence.

$$  S((a_n)_{n=0}^\infty) = (a_n)_{n=1}^\infty  $$

This criterion of invariance under $S$ means that any initial finite segment of the sequence does not matter.  Which should sound familiar ... does a (Calculus I) sequential limit change if you insert or delete a finite initial segment?

Comment: But how about $x \in (\ell^\infty(\Bbb{N})) \setminus c_0$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter : Not *actually* the question being asked.  "... it seems this must be a constant sequence ... Is this not the case? If not, why not and what fits the bill?"